# How can BigQuery SQL give different DISTINCT and GROUP BY results?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We seem to be getting two different, mutually incompatible results from legacy SQL and standard SQL in Google Big Query.

Here is our standard SQL Query...which gives an answer with 218,529 rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(EID)
FROM test.ourBQtable
```

Here is our legacy SQL Query...

```
SELECT COUNT(EID) AS Total, EID 
FROM [ourBQproject:test.ourBQtable] 
GROUP BY EID 
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

This shows results that look like the table below but yet *also* shows 218,529 rows of results:

```
Total     EID
376       jb+qLvHMm5JrMkNybAi6uC75FzgsGcNQhJ19IeWFDcQ=
352       JGqNBgicm+mpcYBS4K7AI2WXI3xaSgMkktb+7oOjjnQ=
```

How is it possible to have what appears to be duplicate EIDs (376 of them as shown in one case in the table) - but when using the DISTINCT(EID) command - the number of rows doesn't decrease? Shouldn't DISTINCT be filtering out all the duplicate rows? Do we really have duplicate rows?

What are we missing in our understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code appears to be working exactly correctly.

`DISTINCT EID` is saying that there are 218,529 different values of `EID`.  This should be returning one row for each of the 218,529 different `EID`s.

When you use `GROUP BY`, you are getting one row for each of the `EID`s.  In this case, you get the same number.

Try running this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_rows, COUNT(DISTINCT EID) as num_eids
FROM test.ourBQtable;
```

This will show the number of rows in the table and the number of distinct values of `EID` (ignoring `NULL` values)`.

Comment: Why would COUNT(EID) with the GROUP BY give a result of 376? How are there 376 values for that particular EID - but also just one row for each EID?

Comment: Got it - we see what you are saying now. The query is grouping and collapsing all the values before doing the count.

Answer (score 1):

Below two query are equivalent and return same number or rows - one per each unique EID

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT EID
FROM test.ourBQtable
```

and

```sql
SELECT EID 
FROM test.ourBQtable 
GROUP BY EID
```

That explains why number of output rows are the same

Now, in second query you added COUNT(EID)

```sql
SELECT COUNT(EID) AS Total, EID 
FROM test.ourBQtable 
GROUP BY EID
```

this does not change the number of output rows, but rather adds count of rows in `test.ourBQtable` with respective `EID` (if you sum all these counts  - you will get total rows in the original table)